# Python cx_oracle conversion from varchar2 to date - Error "sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01861"

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

Reading from Oracle database using python sqlalchemy - for a *"Date"* field stored as *"varchar2"* in the source .

Sample : Test_col format in Oracle "2019-12-20". This is stored as varchar2 in the source DB.

FYI: Converting "varchar2 to date" in python:

```
var_1: datetime.strptime('2019-12-20','%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Passing var_1 to below sql which finally looks like below:

```
select * 
FROM stg_test_table 
WHERE to_date(Test_col,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2019-12-20'
```

This is running fine if i run from Oracle developer but running same from Python code, gives below error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) 
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Tried multiple date combinations but none of them seems to be working while running from Python.

Can this be linked to cx_oracle version issue?

Comment: have you ever tried with `date'2019-12-20'` literal instead of `'2019-12-20'` ..?

Comment: Yes i did but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

That's what happens when dates are stored as strings. Although most "dates" have correct format, the one you predicted: `YYYY-MM-DD`, not all of them do.

For example, if someone entered today's date as `08042020` and you applied the mentioned format mask, you'd get

```
SQL> select to_date('08042020', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
select to_date('08042020', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL>
```

What to do? Expect (a lot?) of pain to fix data. Hopefully, it'll taught you (and the others involved in this) to store dates into `DATE` columns.

You could, for example, "intercept" invalid formats by using regular expressions (expecting 4 digits - 2 digits - 2 digits), but it won't help with values as `2020-34-87` because it fits the format, but is nonsense.

Or, you could loop through those values (which is row-by-row meaning slow-by-slow) and discard values for which `TO_DATE` fails.

You could try different format masks, e.g. `YYYYMMDD`, but - as of `20200408`, what is `04` and what is `08`? Both can be days or months.

As I said, there's no easy way out of it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but i did tried running for a single record(for which i can see the exact format in the source DB - 'YYYY'MM'DD')  , for that as well I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i was able to resolve this, key thing here is to pass the format your DB is expecting, you can check this by:

select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

Considering you are passing correct format, covert using usual TO_DATE conversions and this should work.